# We know about Laplacian matrix L = QQ' but what about Q'Q?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let G be a graph with n vertices and m edges. Suppose an orientation is given to each of the edges of G and let Q be the corresponding incidence matrix of G. Does the matrix Q'Q describe something related to G?

Comment: What is $Q'$? Also are you considering directed graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Per the wikipedia entry on incidence matrices, if $Q$ is the incidence matrix of a graph $G$ with $m$ edges, then we have

$$A(L(G)) = Q^T Q - 2I_m $$

where $L(G)$ is the line graph of $G$ and $A(L(G))$ is the adjacency matrix of this line graph.